# Should I bother editing a question's spelling and syntax?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, spelling

I make edits for questions where the sentence syntax is just really bad. Since I don't have editing privileges, the system says that my edit will be "peer reviewed". Does this really happen, or should I not bother?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edits normally get peer reviewed quickly (especially if it is a newer question).

Go ahead and keep submitting edits when you find these cases.

Look at this link at the bottom to see that you have 4 edits approved:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/55409

Comment: Since correct spelling and grammatical correctness help others understand what's going on, I tend to make edits when I spot errors.

Comment: can you explain how to get link like this for yourself, it appears that 55409 it's not an user id(or it is, and i'm just to slippy today), what this number stands for?

Comment: @igor 55409 is the suggested-edit id. For edits that got approved (like [this one of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5663882/revisions)) you'll see that [`suggested`](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/32068) is a link to the approval page. (I found that by digging through your revision history.)

Answer (score 7):

As long as you do a thorough job and clean up all the spelling and grammar mistakes then your edits should be approved OK. Don't forget the title either!

It's where people just reformat code, or correct a couple of spelling mistakes and leave other (potentially more serious) problems untouched where you will find edits being rejected.

Comment: I always approve edits that just reformat code (as in, add the four-space indent), even if they leave the atrocious prose around intact. I reject tiny edits that just correct a couple of spelling errors without fixing other glaring problems. I urge others to do the same: making code readable is a huge improvement for potential answerers who'll decide whether to bother spending time on the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: by all means, please do - the amount of posts that needs editing is overwhelming. Usual editing recommendations apply: keep the author's intent, and edit if it improves the post substantially (which is often the case with lolcat-grammar-posts).

When you do that, people with full edit privileges ([currently 2000+, IIRC](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)) can approve or reject your edit - with this being a global site, this usually happens within minutes.

For the complete explanation, see the SO blog: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: "lolcat-grammar-posts". [LOL](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/LOL#Initialism).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: [im in ur internetz asking 4 teh codez](http://lolcode.com/examples/hai-world) ;)