# Pending edits before acceptance

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Is there a place to review your pending edits on Stack Overflow? I've looked all over and can't find any place it lists them apart from your reputation breakdown once they're accepted.

Comment: did you look under "Activity" and make certain "All" selected?

Answer (score 2):

We can't find exactly pending suggested edits but you can see all your suggested edits. Go to [your profile > activity > suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599393/rainydaymatt?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Answer (score 2):

No. As [hims056 noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160445/50049), all you can do is view your suggestions, which shows their status.

Theoretically, since [suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) [don't have a shelf life](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98656/expire-time-for-suggested-edits), one *could* suggest a substantial number of edits while several just 'lingered' for protracted amounts of time, thus making the list sort-able make more sense.

I really doubt that such a scenario would actually come to pass, however, which is probably why there's no way to do it.

Comment: Then again, every time I say 'that would not happen' when it comes to Stack Overflow, it happens.

Comment: Quick, say "an increase in question quality in [tag:php] would not happen"! `</offtopic>`